# Two weapon fighting using double slice and power attack at same time

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, damage, attack, two-weapon-fighting

I am helping a new player create a character and he wants to use two weapon fighting. He is joining the campaign I am in and will be  starting out as a 7th level slayer

Assuming 18 strength and using 2 short swords how would using power attack and double slice work for the off hand attack?

For the primary hand the damage is +8(4 from strength 4 from power attack) and for off hand damage is +6(4 from strength 2 from power attack). Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Her BAB is +7/+2, adding her Strength bonus (+4) that goes to +11/+6, taking -2 from *second level* power attack (+4 to damage, -2 to hit), then the character should be sitting at +9/+4 (1d6+8) when only using her primary hand to attack, and +7/+7/+2 (1d6+8, 1d6+6 and 1d6+8 again) when using both hands to attack.

> For the primary hand the damage is +8(4 from strength 4 from power attack)

Assuming he hasn't [Studied](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/SLAYER/#TOC-Studied-Target-Ex-) his target yet, yes. Which he should, as it adds a flat **+2 to attack and damage** against his target, for a total of +10 damage, and all it costs is a *Swift Action* at 7th level.

> and for off-hand damage is +6(4 from strength 2 from power attack).

Yes, because of [Double Slice](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/double-slice-combat/). Again, against a studied target this should be +8 damage.

Everything about [Power Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/) is correct.

Comment: Why aren't they at +7/+2/+7  with two weapons? Isn't the secondary weapon's attack bonus calculated from the primary/first BAB number?

Comment: Its always annotated from highest to lowest. But fixed the damage from second and third attacks.